# Simple URL Re-Write Rule Not Working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I am trying to re-write this:

```
http://www.domain.com/sample/comments/68
```

Into this:

```
http://www.domain.com/sample/comments/index.php?submissionid=68
```

Here is what the .htaccess file looks like in both the directory represented by "sample" above and the directory "comments":

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^comments/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?submissionid=$1 [NC,L]
```

The first URL (`http://www.domain.com/sample/comments/68`) goes to a 404 error.  I have checked, and mod_rewrite appears to be enabled.  Also, when I manually enter the second URL, the correct page pulls up.

Any idea why my the URL re-write is not working?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090422/doing-a-url-re-write, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130779/advice-for-getting-mod-rewrite-to-work, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118690/url-re-write-rule-not-working

I think you should add additional information to your other questions instead of reposting the same question over and over..

Comment: Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Can you try adding a `/`: `RewriteRule ^/comments/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?submissionid=$1 [NC,L]` It's necessary in `RewriteCond`, not sure about here but worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, but I tried that and it didn't work.  I do appreciate the effort, though.

Comment: @John: For starters you should really only have one `.htaccess` file. While I don't see any negative side-effect of having them both (the rule should only match in one place), it's much easier to work out the quirks if you only approach the problem from a single angle. What directory is your `index.php` file in?

Comment: @Tim... that makes sense about the .htaccess files, I was just putting a copy in both directories in case that was the problem.  I have an index file in sample/ and another on in comments/.  But that shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: @John: It's not a problem, but to be able to help you define the `RewriteRule` et al successfully, we need to know exactly where you want the request to go. You want it to go to the index file in the comments directory, right?

Comment: @Tim, yes, I want it to re-direct to the index.php in the comments/ directory

Answer (score 0):

Using your `.htaccess` file in your comments directory, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)?$ index.php?submissionid=$1 [NC,L]
```

And unless you need it, I'd just get rid of the `.htaccess` file in your sample directory. If you get any sort of error, and you have access to your server's error logs (I forget if you mentioned whether or not you do already), please post the last few entries of those as it will help us diagnose where things might be going wrong.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I tried it and it still didn't work.  But I appreciate your help.  I just called my hosting company and they told me how to enable the error logs.  I won't have access to them for about a day.

Comment: Oh, weird..Hm. Alright, well, once you're able to get the logs, please edit this (or one of your other questions) to include that information, and hopefully at that point I or someone else will have an answer for you that'll work.